# How do I resolve a merge conflict with SVN properties?

Tags: svn

This has been bugging me for a long time -- how do I properly resolve a merge conflict within the SVN properties set on a directory?  Say for instance there are two developers working on a project where svn:ignore is set on some directory.  If both developers make changes to this property, when the second one updates, they will see a merge conflict.

Unlike file merge conflicts, a single file is generated in the directory called "dir_conflicts.prej", which the second developer must read and manually correct.  Usually, what I end up doing is reverting all my changes to the local copy, then re-setting these properties manually with the info in dir_conflicts.prej.  However, this is rather cumbersome when dealing with a big list of URLs in an svn:externals property, as many of our projects use.

There has got to be a better way to do this -- does anybody know how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a quick update after some additional research -- it is *not* possible to easily merge SVN properties.  My originally described method (revert, merge data from .prej files, propset, re-commit) appears to be the best way to deal with this type of problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to +1 this answer.
Mine deals with the svn:externals property and an anit-pattern in it's usage.  Not the right place to go into detail, but I just thought I'd gripe here anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

> I tried to use **Team->Edit Property Conflicts** but my STS got hanged and not responded hence I forced close.

It is possible to solve with **TortoiseSVN**

> This is how I resolved

- select the folder where the `dir_conflicts.prej` is located
- right-click **TortoiseSVN -> Resolve...**
- It will then ask to resolve property conflict
- Do Resolve and save

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime this is possible in Eclipse+Subclipse (Indigo) using the function

> Team->Edit Property Conflicts

(just tried with conflicting svn:ignore properties)

This function opens a dialog which shows both properties versions (local and repository), where you can copy&paste and then resolve the conflict using Team->Mark Resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could offer a more hopeful solution but from my experience its not currently possible to merge svn properties using TortoiseSVN. See http://svn.haxx.se/tsvn/archive-2008-09/0212.shtml.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a merge conflict on commit/update or branch merge?

The [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) is pretty clear about the svn:ignore property in particular:

> Subversion does not assume that every
>   file or subdirectory in a working copy
>   directory is intended for version
>   control. Resources must be explicitly
>   placed under Subversion's management
>   using the svn add or svn import 
>   commands.

...

> To force every user of that repository to add patterns for those resources to their run-time configuration areas would be not just a burden, but has the potential to clash with the configuration needs of other working copies that the user has checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, SVN appears to use the dir_conflicts.prej file to derive the fact that the directory has a conflict. If you intend to manually address the conflict, you can simply delete the dir_conflicts.prej file and then manually set the svn properties as you want them. (Of course making sure to get what you need from the .prej file before you delete it!)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar conflict.  I opened `dir_conflicts.prej` in a text editor and saw that the `svn ignore list` had been changed. Luckily, the contents of the list were the same, only the ordering changed. So in `TortoiseSVN 1.9.3`, I just right-click on the folder then `TortoiseSVN -> Resolve...`.  And the conflict was fixed.